# How parse JSON in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Get data on a page in JSON format, how can they be present in table form, for example.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/use_profile")
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    ProfileService profileService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/my",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getProfile(Principal principal){
        try {
            final String name = principal.getName();
            Profile profile = profileService.getProfileByUserLogin(name);
            return profile;
        }
    catch (Exception e){
        return "Error get Profile: " + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

**In JSP:**

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var service = '/use_profile';
>     var RestGet = function (id) {
>         $.ajax({
>             type: 'GET',
>             url: service + "/" + id,
>             dataType: 'json',
>             async: false,
>             success: function (result) {
>                 $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result));
> 
>             },
>             error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
>                 $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
>             }
>         });
>     };
>     RestGet('my'); </script>

><div class="panel-body" id="result">
```

**Result:**

> {"id":4,"login":"user","name":"Ivan","surname":"Ivanov","city":"Spb","interests":"many","avatar":null,"aboutMe":null}

how can parse this data in JSP, for example view in table form??

Comment: you are calling it from javascript method, at this stage jsp will be finalized. you will not be able to use any feature of jsp. jsp(java server page) executes at server side. not on client side

Comment: how to get data from the server and view it in the right form, without reloading the page?

Comment: If you dont want to build table through JSP, then you can use jquery to build dynamic rows in your table, on success of your REST call. Iterate on JSON response and build rows one by one

Comment: _"how can parse this data in JSP_" Your example already does that. _"for example view in table form"_ create the appropriate HTML structure.

Comment: yes, but i can get only all structure, how can get, for example only value of "login"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<c:import>` tag of JSTL to send a call to your API endpoint and then contains the response in a variable. Below is an example:

```
<c:import var="myData" url="/use_profile/my"/>
<c:out value="${myData}"/>
```

And then use ${myData} to construct your table.

Comment: if write  <c:out value="${myData}"/> all is well. But if, for example,   <c:out value="${profile.login}"  /> - Error 500

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#result').html(JSON.parse(result));
```